# SQL Error: Could not find stored procedure 'sp_cleanup_history_table'

Tags: sql-server-2017, sql-server-express

Seeing errors in the SQL error log hourly on a recently patched SQL Express 2017 CU26 instance.  Errors are below.
Feels like something system generated from the stored procedure name but very little information.  I did wonder if it was linked to Change tracking?

> Message Could not find stored procedure 'sp_cleanup_history_table'.

> Message Error: 2812, Severity: 16, State: 62.

Comment: Could this [Microsoft KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5006029-fix-assertion-failure-may-occur-when-sp-cleanup-history-table-is-run-in-sql-server-2017-0e59036a-9ef2-44ea-998e-76c703928894) be regarding your issue?

Comment: Hi mate I did think it could be, but we upgraded to CU26

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?
Just patched to CU27 today and this error started to appear

Comment: Hi HansL 
Sadly not, still trying to resolve it and I am pushing for my place to open a case with MS. For us it is only an express version of SQL and doesn't "seem" to be causing any issues but I am not happy.   I think the owner is waiting for CU28 to come out in the hope that correct its.. against my better judgement

Comment: Just a note: I went from CU22 to CU27 and that error started to occur. I then uninstalled CU27, installed CU26 and then CU27 and the error has disappeared. Maybe it would have worked by only uninstalling and reinstalling CU27, who knows.